# displaying list of combinations in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 numbers 1 to 5.  I require assistance on displaying all combinations of those 5 numbers. I do not want to know quantity of combinations these 5 numbers make but only what the combinations are  e.g  12345, 12344, 12432 etc displayed in open office or excel spreadsheet. There are several answers from programming point of view but i require a formula or vba coding in excel or open office.

Comment: Have you even tried yourself? If so, show us your work. If not, well.. try

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button for suggesting a new unique row combination of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139109/button-for-suggesting-a-new-unique-row-combination-of-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in a variety of ways, but I would look at the 'For loop' object or would use the 'For i = 1 to' methodology to accomplish this.